# OnRoomListUpdate not working but OnCreatedRoom working fine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

It was working but no longer working and I don't know why.

Error the room! because Game does not exist !
but when I created room OncreatedRoom method is working fine.
OMG! Where is the problem ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried debug.logging the count of roomList to check if there is anything in the list? I don't see why I wouldn't print besides there being no RoomInfo's in the list

Comment: How many days I have not been able to solve the problem, I did not fully understand what you said?

Comment: I am extremely confused,player listing doesn't work either!

Comment: There is a high chance that there is nothing in the list since the foreach loop is not called.

Comment: We gotta find out why it wasn't called.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved!

```
PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomName, new RoomOptions { MaxPlayers = playerLimit });
```

to

```
PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomName, new RoomOptions { MaxPlayers = playerLimit, IsVisible = true });
```

Working fine!